# Instance creation based on primary data

Tags: java, inputstream

A `dat` file contains information in the following format, which is written using `writeUTF`:
`Fruit, Colour, Taste, Yes/No` , the last one being either Yes or No, however, it's a string.

Now, a class is defined as follows

```
public class Food {
    private String name;
    private String colour;
    private String taste;
    private boolean availability;


    public Food(String name, String colour, String taste, boolean availability) {
        this.name = name;
        this.colour = colour;
        this.taste = taste;
        this.availability = availability;
    }


}
```

When I read the `dat` file with:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("food.dat");
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(fis);
```

Can I somehow convert a line of text immediately into an instance of `Food`? The tricky bit is the `String -> boolean`.

Initially I wanted to add each line of the file to an `ArrayList`, then split each line from `,` and add it into a String massive and use `if` logic to handle the `Yes/No` part, but what if there are thousands of lines of this information? This approach does not appeal too much.

Provided this isn't written using `ObjectOutputStream`, sadly (an assignment of some sort, I didn't create the rules). Is there a way to read a line from the file and create an instance based on the information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why add everything into a list? Read each line via readUTF, split on commas, then have a method that generates a Food object from the 4 components. Then add your Food objects to whatever container you want.

```
public Food (String[] data){
  if (data==null || data.length!=4){
     // error handling
  }
  this.name=data[0];
  ...
  this.availability="Yes".equals(data[3])
}
```

Comment: The availability parameter is a boolean. Will this not create a problem?

Comment: You create a second constructor: you have one with 4 parameters, you keep it, then you add the one I gave you for creating from a text line.

Comment: I understand, but what if I created an instance using the original constructor and then wanted to ``DataOutputStream`` it into the already existing file. Do I then define a method in which I change the boolean value to a text before writing?

Comment: To write, do the opposite: writeUTF(this.availability?"Yes":"No")

Comment: OH, I wasn't aware of you could do that. Much much appreciated, now I understands how this works.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do that. And to do that you need to know the format of the data and write a parser accordingly.

1) If input line (or) data is delimited with `, | :`,   then split the data and create `Food` object for each line. Set the data in the object using setters methods.

```
String[] splitData = input.split("delimiter");
//length and error check of SplitData
Food food = new Food();
food.setName(splitData[0])); 
...
```

(or)

Pass the input line to the Food object via Constructor, and let the constructor do the split and data assignment.

```
   Food(String input){
          String[] splitData = input.split("delimiter");
          //length and error check of SplitData
          name = splitData[0];
          ...
     }
```

Once you create the `Food` object, you can add it to any collection depending on your requirement.